# Is there any disavantages/drawbacks of storing commas after arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I've seen some of this "lazy coding technique" lately when creating arrays (in PHP):

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'mr magoo',
        'pet' => 'dog',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'superman',
        'pet' => 'cat',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'the hulk',
        'pet' => 'bear',
    ),
}
```

I absolutely see the point of having commas after each array, because it's easy to insert or delete some array without having to care about adding/deleting commas. (If I want to delete superman I just delete those rows)

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'mr magoo',
        'pet' => 'dog',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'the hulk',
        'pet' => 'bear',
    ),
}
```

**Is there are any distadvantages/drawbacks using this "technique"?**
(I think what's really bugging me is that I think that PHP should generate an error or at least a warning because this commas is really not needed)

In javascript I know that there could be issues with some browsers (*internet explorer of course)* when having a comma (where it merely shouldn't be)

```
var info = {'mr maggo', 'hukl',}
```

but javascript is of course on the client-side, so that's another thing.

Comment: i think this covers it too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829581/why-do-php-array-examples-leave-a-trailing-comma

Comment: Problem when you're switching between PHP and javascript a lot, and get in the habit of just adding those trailing commas automatically, forgetting that you're editing a js file

Comment: @MarkBaker - yes, but I sure hope that I know when I'm editing php vs. javascript :-)

Comment: The perils of "muscle memory" as my sporting colleagues would advise me

Comment: How do I handle this? I see there are duplicates of this question, and I've got my answer from other question, but I can't delete this question because I've got an answer here.

Comment: I've voted myself to close my own question :-)