# How to use foreach() properly in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

It is my first time coding in PHP. I am trying to return an array which contains of the amount of each type of cash

```
public function test($a){
    $a = [];
        $cash = array(
            '20'   => 0,
            '30'   => 0,
            '40'   => 0,
            '50'  => 0,
            '60'  => 0,
            '70'  => 0,
            '80' => 0,
        );

        foreach($a as $k => $v) {
            if (array_key_exists("$k",$cash) && $v!= null ) {
                $cash[$k] += 1;
            }
        }

        return  $cash;
    }
```

When I try testing the code I get the error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: I test it with PHPÙnit where I call `$this->assertEquals($expected, $this->TestClass->findCashPayment($a));`

Comment: Let me rephrase: what's `$a`?

Comment: It is an array.

Comment: It's not. `public function test(array $a){`

Comment: I don't see how foreach can fail here since you redefine $a to be an empty array. Are you sure this is the line in your unit test that is failing? Or did you change anything after you ran your test?

Comment: I get the error: `"Failed asserting that two arrays are equal"`. The expected array doesn't match the one I get

Comment: Please edit your question with your _real_ issue, the input that you provide to that function, and the output that you expect from it

Comment: if `$a` is empty, `foreach` (which loops over each of its elements) will do nothing. That's probably why the test fails ;)

Answer (score 0):

the 1st argument for foreach() must be an array. 
$a is not an array
Also note that you are trying to use $count, which was not previously defined as an array. Either that "$cash" assignment should be "$count" or vice-versa.

Comment: My bad :) It's fixed now, but I still get the same error :/

Comment: you must pass an array to your test() function.

Comment: I defined it as an empty array in the beginning, but the test doesn't pass :/

Answer (score 0):

Try calling with `test(array('20' => 0));` and you will not get the error. You are probably calling it with something that is not an array?

Comment: I am not sure what you actually are trying to achieve. Can you please explain further?

Comment: In your revised question you don't use the input. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cash[$key] += 1;
```

should be

```
$cash[$k] += 1;
```

I have included the code that I used for testing here:-

```
<?php
function test($a){
  $cash = array(
    '20' => 0,
    '30' => 0,
    '40' => 0,
    '50' => 0,
    '60' => 0,
    '70' => 0,
    '80' => 0,
  );

  foreach($a as $k => $v) {
      if (array_key_exists("$k",$cash) && $v != NULL ) {
        $cash[$k] += 1;
      }
    }
  return  $cash;
}

// code that I have added to test the function from the post question
$testArray = array(
  '20' => 1,
  '30' => 2,
  '40' => 3,
  '50' => 4,
  '60' => 5,
  '70' => 6,
  '80' => 7,
);

$cash = test($testArray);

foreach($cash as $k => $v) {
  echo("\n$k : $v");
}

?>
```

Results:-

```
20 : 1
30 : 1
40 : 1
50 : 1
60 : 1
70 : 1
80 : 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can try removing the comma at the end of your array.

change:    `'80' => 0,`

to:  `'80' => 0`

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo here on Stackoverflow. It's not there in my code

Comment: that's actually common practice, to leave the trailing comma. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829581/why-do-php-array-examples-leave-a-trailing-comma